# Multiple nvd3 graphs and select issue

Tags: nvd3.js

I have multiple nvd3 pie charts in the same page. Now when I try to position them,individually using this code below

```
d3.select(".nv-pieWrap")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,-35)");
```

Only the first graph in the page gets repositioned.  It is said in the nvd3 support document that the select keyword if used in multiple functions,only selects the first element in the page.

Now when I replace "select" with "selectAll",every graph is re-positioned.

I want to position them separately ie the "translate" coordinates would be different in different cases. How would I accomplish that?. Can anyone help?

d3.selectAll(".nv-pieWrap")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,-35)");

Answer (score 0):

I've got two solutions of the problem.

1. One solution is you can specify 'transform' attribute not as a constant "translate(0,-35)" but a function instead. And within the function decide which coordinates you need based on the chart's index:

   ```
   d3.selectAll(".nv-pieWrap")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { 
         // i is a chart index
         if (i === 0) {
            return 'translate(0,-35)';
         } else {
            return 'translate(100,-35)';
         }
      });
   ```
2. Another solution is to wrap your code

   ```
   d3.select(".nv-pieWrap")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,-35)");
   ```

   into a transforming function which takes a node and transform as a parameter, e.g.

   ```
   var transform = function(chart, transform) {
      return  
       d3.select(chart)
         .attr("transform", transform); 
   }
   draw("#pieChart1", "translate(0,-35)");
   draw("#pieChart2", "translate(100,-35)");
   ```